# Como contar registros de 3 tablas unidas por una llave foranea?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql-9.3

[image: Tengo una tabla principal]

[image: La segunda tabla depende de la principal(1)]

[image: La tercera tabla tambien depende la tabla princiapl(1)]

Tengo una tabla principal con un registro, y en las otras dos tablas pueden haber varios registros que dependen del registro de la tabla 1.

Yo necesito que me muestre 1 solo registro como aparece en la imagen 1, pero agregandole 3 columnas mas que corresponden a:

1 - Sumatoria de los valores de la columnaa 'valorabonado' de la tabla 2 que coincidan con la llave primaria de la tabla 1 y la cantidad de filas sumadas.

2 - Total de registros de la tabla 3 que coincidan con la llave primaria de la tabla 1.

Yo tengo este sql pero la sumatoria no me funciona:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(p.idpagos)) as pagos, sum(valorabonado), count(DISTINCT(e.identrada)) FROM pagoperiodico pg
INNER JOIN pagos p USING(idpago)
INNER JOIN entrada e ON pg.idpago=e.idpago
WHERE pg.idpago=7334
GROUP BY pg.idpago
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. En cuanto a tu pregunta no entiendo `entrada e ON pg.idpago=e.idpago`, por lo que veo `entradas` solo tiene `idpagoperiodico` no `idpago`. Es correcto?

Comment: la tabla entradas tiene 3 columnas, una que es el consecutivo propio de la tabla, la otra columna es la clave foranea(idpagoperiodico) de la tabla principal, y la 3ra columna es la fechaentrada.... Estaba haciendo mal en colocar INNER JOIN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, ya que has dado por aceptada la respuesta anterior doy por cierto que la clave que relaciona las tres tablas es `idpagoperiodico` por lo que una solución posible podría ser:

```
SELECT  pg.idpagoperiodico,
        p.ValorAbonado,
        p.CantidadPagos,
        COUNT(e.identrada)               AS 'CantidadEntradas'
        FROM pagoperiodico pg
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT idpagoperiodico,
                      SUM(valorabonado)  AS 'ValorAbonado',
                      COUNT(1)           AS 'CantidadPagos'
                      FROM pagos
                      GROUP BY idpagoperiodico
                ) p
            ON p.idpagoperiodico = pg.idpagoperiodico
        LEFT JOIN entrada e
            ON e.idpagoperiodico = pg.idpagoperiodico
        GROUP BY pg.idpagoperiodico, 
                 p.ValorAbonado, 
                 p.CantidadPagos
```

Explicación:

- El primer `LEFT JOIN` apunta a una subconsulta que agrupa cada `idpagoperiodico` y obtiene la suma de `valorabonado` y la cantidad de registros que hemos agrupado en `pagos`.
- El siguiente `LEFT JOIN` apunta directamente a `entrada` pero no habría problema con las repeticiones de filas ya que estamos agrupando al final y contando los registros de esta tabla mediante `COUNT(e.identrada)`
- La idea de usar `LEFT` en lugar de `INNER` es simplemente para tener siempre todos los `pagoperiodico.idpagoperiodico` aunque no tengan filas en las tablas `pagos` y `entrada`, ahora si solo te interesan aquellos casos dónde exista relación con alguna de las dos tablas, simplemente modifica los `LEFT` por `INNER`.

**Nota**: Te sugiero que siempre indiques la etiqueta del motor de base de datos adecuada, en la pregunta has indicado `postgres` y `mysql`, en este caso creo que la solución debiera funcionar para ambos casos, pero recuerda que el SQL tiene diferencias idiomáticas entre los distintos motores.

Comment: Efectivamente funciona!, lo habia dejado de la primera forma que me dijiste anteiormente... Habria que mirar cual de las dos tiene mejor rendieminto, pues los registros de la primera tabla(T1) son bastantes, por ejemplo, pueden haber 10 registros de una sola persona, pero solo debo agarrar el ultimo que se le registro a esa persona, y pueden haber 1000 mil personas, y esas mil pueden tener varios registros etc, la solucion ya la tengo, seleccionando el MAX(fechainicio). Bueno, solo te comentaba.. Y el motor de base de datos es inicialmente para postgresql y lo estoy migrando a sqlite. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Dividiendo la pregunta en partes:

> 1-Sumatoria de los valores de la columnaa 'valorabonado' de la tabla 2 que coincidan con la llave primaria de la tabla 1 y la cantidad de filas sumadas

Con la función SUM() tienes el sumatorio de 'valorabonado' y con la función COUNT() la cantidad de filas sumadas. Haciendo un JOIN de la Tabla 1 y 2 tienes el resultado:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
SUM(T2.valorabonado) 
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON (T1.Id = T2.Id) 
WHERE T1.Id = 7334
```

> 2- Total de registros de la tabla 3 que coincidan con la llave primaria de la tabla 1.

Esto se consigue igualmente con un COUNT(*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM T3 
WHERE T3.Id = 7334
```

Y para 'empaquetarlo' todo en una cosulta, puedes poner la segunda consulta como una query anidada. Te quedaría así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COL_NAME1, 
       SUM(T2.valorabonado) AS COL_NAME2, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3 WHERE T3.Id = 7334) AS COL_NAME3 
FROM T1 JOIN T2
ON (T1.Id = T2.Id) 
WHERE T1.Id = 7334
```

Te faltaría substituir el nombre de las tablas (he usado T1, T2 y T3), poner nombre a las columnas dínamicas y en el SELECT añadir las columnas que quieres mostrar de T1 (idpagoperiodico, nombre, fechainicio, fechafinal)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias hermano!! Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de interpretar mi consulta... Y Yo sabia que tenia que realizar un sql interno, pero no lograba donde ubicarla. Dios le bendiga. Gracias por ayudar.